# create smoother curve for exponential function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have x,y (`order`, `Hill`) data and want to fit my data smoothly, however my curves look not smooth. I am using `curve_fit` function and `matplotlib`

my code looks following:

```
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.exp(-b*x)+c


for i in range(len(hill_numbers)):
    Hill = np.array(hill_numbers[i])

    print Hill, order 

    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, order, Hill, p0=(1, 1e-6, 1), maxfev=10000)


    plt.plot(order, Hill, ls="none", marker='.', color='grey')

    plt.plot(order, func(order, *popt),'-')



plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 3, step=1))


plt.xlabel('order q')
plt.ylabel('Hill numbers')
plt.show()
```

I have following data

`Hill` looks like this:

```
[19.        12.14       7.5426009]
[19.        12.14       7.5426009]
```

and `order`

```
[0,1,2]
[0,1,2]
```

my plot looks like this 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a fine x-mesh to plot the continuous smooth line as following. This is done using, for example, `linspace` as `order_fine = np.linspace(order[0], order[-1], 100)` and then passing `order_fine` to your plot function using the fit coefficients `*popt`

```
import numpy as np
hill_numbers = [[19, 12.14, 7.5426009], [19, 17.14, 15.5426009]]
order = np.array([0,1,2])

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.exp(-b*x)+c

for i in range(len(hill_numbers)):
    order_fine = np.linspace(order[0], order[-1], 100)
    Hill = np.array(hill_numbers[i])
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, order, Hill, p0=(1, 1e-6, 1), maxfev=10000)

    plt.plot(order, Hill, ls="none", marker='.', color='grey')
    plt.plot(order_fine, func(order_fine, *popt),'-')
```

[image]